# 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IListItem[]>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

I have the following error:

```
[ts]
Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IListItem[]>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IListItem[]'.
(method) Promise<{
    value: IListItem[];
}>.then<void>(onFulfilled?: (value: {
    value: IListItem[];
}) => void | Thenable<void>, onRejected?: (error: any) => void | Thenable<void>): Promise<void> (+2 overloads)
```

In the following piece of code, what am I missing?

```
import { SPHttpClient, SPHttpClientResponse } from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { IWebPartContext } from "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base";
import { IListItem} from "./models/IListItem";
import { IFactory } from "./IFactory";
import { INewsListItem } from "./models/INewsListItem";
import { IDirectoryListItem } from "./models/IDirectoryListItem";
import { IAnnouncementListItem } from "./models/IAnnouncementListItem";

export class ListItemFactory implements IFactory {
    private _listItems: IListItem[];
    public getItems(requester: SPHttpClient, siteUrl: string, listName: string): Promise<IListItem[]> {
        switch(listName) {
            case "GenericList":
                let items: IListItem[];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
                return requester.get(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('${listName}')/items?$select=Title,Id,Modified,Created,Author/Title,Editor/Title&$expand=Author,Editor`,
                SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json;odata=nometadata",
                        "odata-version": ""
                    }
                })
                .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<{ value: IListItem[] }> => {
                    return response.json(); 
                })
                .then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
                    items=json.value.map((v,i)=>({ 
                        key: v.id,
                        id: v.id,
                        title: v.title,
                        created: v.created,
                        createdby: v.Author.Title,
                        modified: v.modified,
                        modifiedby: v.Editor.Title                        
                    }));
```

Update 1:

the consumer of the above method:

```
 // read items using factory method pattern and sets state accordingly
  private readItemsAndSetStatus(): void {
    this.setState({
      status: "Loading all items..."
    });

    const factory: ListItemFactory = new ListItemFactory();
    factory.getItems(this.props.spHttpClient, this.props.siteUrl, this.props.listName)
    .then((items: IListItem[]) => {
      const keyPart: string = this.props.listName === "GenericList" ? "" : this.props.listName;
        // the explicit specification of the type argument `keyof {}` is bad and
        // it should not be required.
        this.setState<keyof {}>({
          status: `Successfully loaded ${items.length} items`,
          ["Details" + keyPart + "ListItemState"] : {
            items
          },
          columns: buildColumns(items)
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: try casting `return requester.get(` promise to `IListItems[]`

Comment: you are not returning any `Promise<IListItems[]>` from your last `.then(` you are actually resolving it hence if you change the return type of `public getItems` to `public getItems():void` it should work. However this is not the right way resolving a promise in your service class. The `.then` part should be in your component class which consumes the service . it's quite clear from the error message `Promise<void>`

Comment: please see the update, I added the consumer code, @Niladri, can you let me know what is the best way to do this.

Comment: @LuisValencia your consumer code looks fine , can you try adding `return json.value.map` at the end of the last `.then` block in your `public getItems` method instead of the `items`, you are not returning any value from there also you are missing a closing `})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `then` callback assigns to a global `items` variable, but does not return any value - so the promise resolves with `undefined`. You need to use

```
.then((json: { value: IListItem[] }) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.value));
    return json.value.map((v,i) => ({
//  ^^^^^^
        key: v.id,
        id: v.id,
        title: v.title,
        created: v.created,
        createdby: v.Author.Title,
        modified: v.modified,
        modifiedby: v.Editor.Title                        
    }));
});
```

Comment: yup I noticed the same